# Reading a text field and comparing to an array object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sdk

I have setup an array full of words as objects. I am trying then trying to compare what the user enters in a uitextfield to an object in the array to see if they match.

I have captured a pointer to the uitextview in one of the delegate methods, however I cannot compare the text field contents to the object in the array. I assume that this is because one is a string and one is an array object ? Do I need to cast one of the variables somehow ?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to test whether the user's input matches *any* member of your array, you should do something like this:

```
NSString *input = textField.text;
BOOL wordFound = NO;
for(NSString *candidate in self.possibleWordsArray) { 
    if( [input isEqual:candidate] ) {
        wordFound = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if(wordFound) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Notes:

- We are comparing the input string against each member of the array in turn. This gives an explicit meaning to the idea of matching a string against an array.
- When we find a matching string, we set the flag `wordFound` to `YES` and then stop searching (using the `break` statement). If no match is found, the `wordFound` flag remains at its original value of `NO`.
- Always use `isEqual` to test equality between strings, never `==`; the later will usually work, but then break occasionally. This is because `==` only tests whether the two pointers point to the same memory location, whereas you might have two copies of an identical string in different memory locations.

Comment: Hi David. Many thanks for your help. Before I read your answer I did this, which works if ([textField.text isEqualToString : keepName]) {
  
  Success = YES;
  [self shootTarget];
  
 }
 
 else { [self gameFail];
  
 }
 
 return YES;